# How should I structure my plugins developments and how to apply a patch to a patch in svn?

Tags: svn, branch, patch

I just started to develop redmine plugins and patches and I am using svn. I have the next structure:

```
doc/
src/
src/branches/
src/plugins/
src/patches/
src/trunk/
```

My idea was to create a branch from trunk for each plugin or patch I am going to develop. The plugins folder was intended to store different versions of the plugins and the patches folder the versions of he patches.

I am facing the next problem right now: I created a branch issue_x to develop a patch. After the first version, I used `svn diff > patch.diff` to get the patch. Then I saved it in the patches folder and then applied it to the trunk with `patch -p0 < ../patch.diff`. Cool, but I have to make a little modification to the patch because there was an error caught in production.

What should I do?

- Create a new patch to fix the error?
- Fix the error, create a whole patch (including all changes made), revert the patch in trunk and then reapply the new patch?
- Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Subversion (and any SCM in common) way is "Merge changes" from different development lines.

I.e instead of diff-patch way you use svn internal technique - merge branch to trunk, re-merge after some changes added in branch while you don't get needed result

Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html), it's useful thing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using patches instead of merges. That is quite strange.

The most obvious thing (to me) would be to branch off of `issue_x`, fix the bug, merge back into `issue_x` and then merge `issue_x` back into `trunk`.

In your scenario, I suggest you make your changes to fix the bug in `issue_x`, create a patch, and apply that to `trunk`. You should still learn about [SVN branching and merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html), from the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/) though.